# Pushing value to existing cache value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set a value to an existing cache. I have something like this:

`Cache::put('key',['foo', 'bar'], $expiresAt);`

Now how can I push `'sad'` value to this key without deleting last values?

Need something like this after pushing value and getting cache:

`{'foo', 'bar', 'sad'}`

Comment: Use `get()` from cache, add your value to array, `put()` it again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Cache::put('key',['foo', 'bar'], $expiresAt);
$key = Cache::get('key');
$key[] = 'sad';
Cache::put('key', $key, $expiresAt);
```

Just get the existing cache, update it and put it back again.

Comment: Note that this can cause problems. For example, lets say you have several jobs all appending to the array, when 2 jobs call Cache::get at the exact same time resulting in them getting the same array, then append, and then both update, one value will get lost. You can use atomic locks to solve this (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#atomic-locks)