# Laravel Cache Facade - set vs put

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I use `Cache::set(...)` facade-method for a simple key/value store.

But all [posts I visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110089/pushing-value-to-existing-cache-value-in-laravel)
seem to talk about `Cache::put(...)` method.

What is the difference or advantage of one vs the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set` method is same as `put`

As you can see from https://github.com/illuminate/cache/blob/master/Repository.php#L227 - `set` method delegates all work to `put` method.

`set` method is added only for compatibility with [PSR-16](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-16/) standard.

Comment: Updated answer, because mixed up PSR-6 (Caching Interface) with psr-16 (Common Interface for Caching Libraries).