# Retrieve data according to the other data in the same database table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a **database table** named **config_table** that looks like below:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+---------+
| id | config_name | config_value | user_id |
+----+-------------+--------------+---------+
|  1 | status      | 1            |       1 |
|  2 | title       | Test Title   |       1 |
|  3 | token       | k12345abc    |       1 |
+----+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

With **Laravel Eloquent** I can just create a model and then start retrieving data easily like:

```
<?php

$configs = App\Config::all();

foreach ($configs as $config) {
    echo $config->config_name;
}
```

And get an output:

```
status
title
token
```

But I want to perform like:

Get the **`config_value`** collection by **`config_name`** considering as well the **`user_id`**

```
echo status;
echo title; //which is under the 'config_name' column
```

And the expected output should be

```
1
Test Title //which is the config_value of the config_name 'title'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824781/laravel-load-settings-from-database

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'where' to specify constraints like this:

Select 'config_value' where 'config_name' is 'status'. To get only the first row, use first()

```
$config = App\Config::select('config_value')->where('config_name', 'status')->first();

echo $config->config_value;
```

Similarly, select 'config_value' where 'config_name' is 'title'. To get all the rows, use get(), then you can loop through it.

$configs = App\Config::select('config_value')->where('config_name', 'title')->get();

```
foreach ($configs as $config) {
    echo $config->config_value;
}
```

You can chain this. Select all configs where "config_name" is either 'status' or 'title'.

```
$configs = App\Config::select('config_value')->where('config_name', 'status')->orWhere('config_name', 'title')->get();

foreach ($configs as $config) {
    echo $config->config_value;
}
```

Also, you can use whereIn() to specify multiple values of a column. Select all configs where "config_name" is either 'status' or 'title'.

```
$configs = App\Config::select('config_value')->whereIn('config_name', ['status', 'title'])->get();

foreach ($configs as $config) {
    echo $config->config_value;
}
```