# Store config in database in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, config

I am currently using Laravel 5.2. I want to be able to store config properties (key-value pairs) in database, that I am willing to access from both my application on runtime and the console (either `php artisan` command or `Tinker`).

What is my best option?

- `.env` is one way, but it is not stored in the database, but in a file.
- `Config::get` is another way, but it also writes in files. Can it be configured to write in database?
- `Cache::get` is setup to work with the database, but is temporary, not permanent, so it is out of question.

The reason I am interested in database config, is because we often replace/delete files during deployment. Also it would be nice to store values encrypted. Also important feature here is to be able to easily get values via either `php artisan` or `tinker`

Comment: Interesting idea, I worked with a project before which had a db-config solution. Basically, we had a table with 2 fields: `key` and `value`. Then we had a model for this table(i.e. `DBConfig`) and use the values like `DBConfig::where('key', $yourKey)->first();` So you can use config() for regular config options( db settings need to be loaded from file ofc) and DBConfig for config only found in db. If you want me to elaborate this idea, I wil post it as an answer :)

Comment: @RobBiermann yes this is a good idea. I would like to see it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a migration: `php artisan make:migration CreateSettingsTable`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSettingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('key');
            $table->string('value');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique([
                'key', //I add a unique to prevent double keys
            ]);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('settings');
    }
}
```

2. Make the model: `php artisan make:model Setting`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'key',
        'value'
    ];

    //I would normally do this in a repository,
    // but for simplicity sake, i've put it in here :)
    static public $settings = null;

    static function get($key, $default = null)
    {
        if (empty(self::$settings)) {
            self::$settings = self::all();
        }
        $model = self
            ::$settings
            ->where('key', $key)
            ->first();
        if (empty($model)) {
            if (empty($default)) {
                //Throw an exception, you cannot resume without the setting.
                throw new \Exception('Cannot find setting: '.$key);
            }
            else {
                return $default;
            }
        }
        else {
            return $model->value;
        }
    }

    static function set(string $key, $value)
    {
        if (empty(self::$settings)) {
            self::$settings = self::all();
        }
        if (is_string($value) || is_int($value)) {
            $model = self
                ::$settings
                ->where('key', $key)
                ->first();

            if (empty($model)) {
                $model = self::create([
                    'key' => $key,
                    'value' => $value
                ]);
                self::$settings->push($model);
            }
            else {
                $model->update(compact('value'));
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note here, that I added the get and set functions, together with a static `$settings` variable directly to the model, to keep the example small. Usually I would opt to making a repository or service(not serviceprovider) to handle these functions. This way you only query db once(per request) for all the settings. You could stick this in cache, but that is not part of this answer of now.

3. Run `php artisan migrate` to ge the table in the db.
4. Run `composer dump-autoload` to make sure tinker can find the `Setting` class.
5. Use someting like `php artisan tinker`(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#tinker) to test it, in this case you can do:

```
Setting::set('someKey', 'someValue'); //Set someKey to someValue
Setting::get('someKey'); //Get someKey, throws exception if not found
Setting::get('somekey2', 'someDefault'); //Shows someDefault because somekey2 is not set yet.
```

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: I think you should implement some caching here to prevent repeated DB lookups. Preferably retrieve all settings into a map and just lookup in that map. Refresh the cache whenever a setting changes. Some good stuff here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824781/laravel-load-settings-from-database

Answer (score 1):

I'm using laravel 9, and using package from spatie: [spatie/laravel-settings](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-settings).

If you follow the docs you may set the setting class, for example I want to store payment gateway settings into the database, namely Securepay in Malaysia.

In settings folder, App\Settings will have a new file PaymentGatewaySettings.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Settings;

use Spatie\LaravelSettings\Settings;

class PaymentGatewaySettings extends Settings
{
    public string $env;

    public string $uid;

    public string $auth_token;

    public string $checksum_token;

    public static function group() : string
    {
        return 'payment_gateway';
    }
}
```

In AppSeviceProvider.php we add new line under boot method:

```
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * Payment Gateway settings
         *
         */
        if(DB::table('settings')->where('group', 'payment_gateway')->exists()) {
            config()->set('services', array_merge(config('services'), [
                'securepay' => [
                    'env' => app(SecurepaySettings::class)->env,
                    'uid' => app(SecurepaySettings::class)->uid,
                    'auth_token' => app(SecurepaySettings::class)->auth_token,
                    'checksum_token' => app(SecurepaySettings::class)->checksum_token,
                ]
            ]));
        }
    }
```

If we do not put the `if` statement, it would be an error while want to run php artisan command.

In other cases you may extend the Illuminate\Foundation\Application class, and you may use something like this app()->getSecurePayEnv() in everywhere in you application, but to set the config I'm still using boot method in AppSeviceProvider.php.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I extended Rob Biermann approach to handling json data

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class Setting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'value' => 'array'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'key',
        'value'
    ];

    /**
     * @var Setting[]|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|null
     */
    static public $settings = null;

    static function getAll(string $key, $default = null){
        if (empty(self::$settings)) {
            self::$settings = self::all();
        }
        $keys = explode('.', $key);
        $databaseKey = $keys[0];
        unset($keys[0]);
        $model = self
            ::$settings
            ->where('key', $databaseKey)
            ->first();
        if (empty($model)) {
            if (empty($default)) {
                //Throw an exception, you cannot resume without the setting.
                throw new \Exception('Cannot find setting: ' . $key);
            } else {
                return $default;
            }
        } else {
            return $model->value;
        }
    }

    static function get(string $key, $default = null)
    {
        if (empty(self::$settings)) {
            self::$settings = self::all();
        }
        $keys = explode('.', $key);
        $databaseKey = $keys[0];
        unset($keys[0]);
        $model = self
            ::$settings
            ->where('key', $databaseKey)
            ->first();
        if (empty($model)) {
            if (empty($default)) {
                //Throw an exception, you cannot resume without the setting.
                throw new \Exception('Cannot find setting: ' . $key);
            } else {
                return $default;
            }
        } else {
            if(!empty( $keys)){
                return Arr::get($model->value, implode('.',$keys));
            }
            if(is_string( $model->value)){
                return $model->value;
            }
            if(Arr::has($model->value, 'default')){
                return $model->value['default'];
            }

            return $model->value;

        }
    }

    static function set(string $key, $value)
    {
        if (empty(self::$settings)) {
            self::$settings = self::all();
        }

        $keys = explode('.', $key);
        $databaseKey = $keys[0];
        unset($keys[0]);

        $model = self
            ::$settings
            ->where('key', $databaseKey)
            ->first();

        if (empty($model)) {
            if(!empty($keys)){
                $array = [];
                $model = self::create([
                    'key' => $key,
                    'value' => Arr::set($array, implode('.',$keys), $value)
                ]);
            }
            else{
                $model = self::create([
                    'key' => $key,
                    'value' => $value
                ]);
            }

            self::$settings->push($model);
        } else {
            if(!empty($keys)){
                $old = $model->value;
                if(is_string($old)){
                    $old = ["default" => $old] ;
                }
                if(Arr::has($old, implode('.',$keys))){
                    $old = Arr::set($old, implode('.',$keys), $value);
                }
                else{
                    $old = Arr::add($old, implode('.',$keys), $value);
                }

                $model->update(['value' => $old]);
            }
            else{
                if(is_array($model->value)){
                    $new = $model->value;
                    $new['default'] = $value;
                    $value = $new;
                }
                $model->update(['value' => $value]);

            }

        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

now u can use

```
Setting::get('someKey.key');
Setting::get('someKey.key.key1');
Setting::set('someKey.key', 'test');
Setting::set('someKey.key.key1', 'test');
```